# Is there a difference between linear map and linear transform?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Wikipedia page says there is no difference but when I see reference to a map it's domain and range are specified but in a transform it is not the case. Any suggestion how to view the both?

Comment: They're different names for the same thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually we say *linear transformation*, and yes, it is a synonym for "linear map".

Another term is "linear operator", which usually refers to the case where the domain and codomain are the same.

Comment: It may be interesting to find why two different mathematical word evolved to mean exactly the same meaning? May be came from two different branch of study?

Comment: @Creator If you feel that Eric Auld's answer is sufficient, please accept it. This post was just bumped by Community unnecessarily since it did not have an accepted answer.